# Generic class type parent using reflection

Tags: java, generics, reflection

```
public class Parent {}

public class A extends Parent {}

public class B {}

public class Test {
    private List<A> aList;
    private List<B> bList;
}
```

I was playing around with reflection and generics and created these classes just for fun.

Now I want to print the names of variables in the `Test` class which are of type `List<T extends Parent>`. So I want to print only `"aList"` because `A` extends `Parent`, while `B` does not.

So far I have been able to get the `List` variables. I looked at various methods of reflection but could not extract the type of List `<...>` and see if its superclass is `Parent` or not. Here is my code which currently prints both `"aList"` and `"bList"`:-

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Arrays.stream(Test.class.getDeclaredFields())
            .filter(field -> field.getType().equals(List.class)) // && fieldActualTypeExtendsA
            .forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.getName()));
}
```

What should I add in the filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access field generic type by `field.getGenericType()` which returns implementation of `ParameterizedType` class where is method `getActualTypeArguments()` returning type arguments. This is usable for `List`, `Map`, etc.

Then your code for filtering by parent can look like:

```
Arrays.stream(Test.class.getDeclaredFields())
        .filter(field -> field.getType().equals(List.class)
                && field.getGenericType() instanceof ParameterizedType
                && ((Class) ((ParameterizedType) field.getGenericType()).getActualTypeArguments()[0]).getSuperclass().equals(Parent.class))
        .forEach(field -> System.out.println(field.getName()));
```

You can of course add some safety checks - for example whether array returned by `getActualTypeArguments()` is empty or not.

Comment: thank you, I was looking at methods that came up without casting anything

Comment: You are welcome. In these cases I use IntelliJ IDEA in debug mode and it nicely shows all possibilities which normally remains hidden.